# Lots of OpenEBS questions from new users

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm quite new here so perhaps this happens more often but I noticed suddenly that lot's of questions are being asked on OpenEBS from new users (<10 reputation). Their names make me believe they're from India or so, at least all from the same region. Is this spam or is this more common in September when a new school year starts or ...?

Answer (score 6):

I hadn't thought of a recurrence of [the eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) but a lot of it has been dealt with by the community moderators.

It appeared as a pair accounts working in tandem and alternating posting the same questions and answers on both Stack Overflow and ServerFault.

Answer (score 4):

You are definitely on to something. If you [search for "OpenEBS"](https://serverfault.com/search?q=OpenEBS), you will find only a dozen and half or so questions, but *almost all* of them from new users opening a "new" account in the last 8-10 days.

If you look at those user's posts in StackOverflow, you will see that each *new* user is dropping a barrage of questions and they are all on "OpenEBS."

Somebody is definitely running a scheme to promote OpenEBS. OpenEBS, by the way, is developed and [ran out of India, and looking for funding](https://angel.co/openebs).